# Objectify : How to Migrate an Entity with a String ID to a Long ID

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm trying to change an Entity class with a String @Id to a class with a Long @Id, here is the class :

```
@Entity
public class MyClass extends EntityBaseString{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Ref<MyClass> parent;
    private List<Ref<MyClass>> list = new ArrayList<Ref<MyClass>>();

    public MyClass(){}
    //getters and setters omited
}
```

What I want is to change the superclass from `EntityBaseString` to `EntityBaseLong`, but I want to know what is the better way to do it?

I tried to copy it to another Entity called `MyClassV2` that extends `EntityBaseLong`, and I have made a copy of `MyClass` entities to `MyClassV2` entities. But the problem is that `MyClass`entities are referenced on a lot of other entities, so there is a lot of changes to do on the model if I use `MyClassV2`.

I'm using Objectify v4.

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd like to do that though.

Comment: I need to do that because the class in question was first thinked like a unique (I use the String Id with the name of the Entity to have the unicity behaviour). But now, processes moved and this entity don't have to be unique, so I'm trying to migrate it to Long Id Entity. I was thinking about making a unique String hash depending on the entity content. I will prefer the migration to Long IDs entities than that, but I have a lot of code to change to migrate it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a good story around this right now. Changing object identity is hard, because it really represents a copy-and-delete operation. Objectify currently does not forgive trying to load a Long id into a String id or vice-versa... and doing so is perilous, because a load-then-save operation would actually be a copy operation.

The only way to handle this remotely gracefully is to allow @Id fields to be specified as Object, and letting it be either Long or String. Then you can manage copy/delete on your own. Objectify does not currently allow this, but you could request it as an enhancement: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues

Comment: Thanks you! I will add an issue on GitHub.